# Assigning a user to multiple projects in my PHP application, best approach?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am currently building a web application for my work and you can add tasks, projects and clients. The dilemma I've encountered is that a client can be assigned to multiple projects at once.

The application is being built upon the latest version of Codeigniter 2.0 (if that helps). I am usually pretty good at working out problems like this, but I can't get my head around this one.

One solution I came up with is to store a list of project ID's for the client in a table field called 'belongs_to' and separate them by comma. Sure this method would work, but it just seems a little messy and I am sure that there is another way, my mind just can't come up with the solution.

Your help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You can always use an ORM (I use "Datamapper Overzealous Edition" with codeigniter). It handles relationships within an application way easily.

Comment: I decided to download Datamapper Overzealous Edition and installed it, I am new to using an ORM for interfacing with databases and I just couldn't work out how to implement this into my current application.


The user guide for it is great, I just can't seem to understand how I can implement it and if I need to rename database tables or not. Maybe I'm losing my mind slowly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just have 3 tables:

1. Table *projects*: id, name, etc etc
2. Table *clients*: id, name, etc etc
3. Table *clients2projects*: id, id_project, id_client

In this way the third table maps projects and clients in a many to many relationship

Comment: Fantastic. I can't believe I never thought of that, such an easy and elegant solution to implement and use. Thank you for answering so fast and precisely.

Comment: I'm implementing something very similar to this scenario and this even aided me in my software I'm writing. Thanks nico!